# Android- Picasso sometimes give SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Tags: android, null, picasso, bitmapfactory, imagedownload

I get following error when i download images using Picasso library.

```
SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

The code that I'm using is as follows:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(mySharedPreferences.GetUserCoverImageUrl())
        .placeholder(R.drawable.cover_no_img)
        .fit()
        .into(coverImage_iv);
```

Can you please suggest the solution? I've googled it but couldn't understand the solution.

Comment: data returned from url is bad image or not image at all

Comment: When i hit the url in web browser it is shown properly and even in application sometimes after uninstalling the app then reinstalling causes the successful downloading. I guess after clearing the memory it is able to be downloaded